# git pathspec: Combine "glob" and "exclude" to exclude directories anywhere in the tree?

Tags: git

I would like to run `git ls-files` with a pathspec that will exclude any directory named `foo` and all of its children, anywhere it appears in my repository.

The [git glossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary) makes it seem like the `glob` and `exclude` "magic words" are compatible, and that a pathspec of the form

```
:(exclude,glob):**/foo
```

will achieve my goal. But, when I run

```
git ls-files -- . ':(exclude,glob):**/foo' | grep foo
```

I see a lot of `foo` entries, that I had hoped to filter with that pathspec, appear in the output.

Are these options incompatible? If so, what is the correct way to `git ls-files` and filter out subdirectories that appear anywhere but match a specific name? I would prefer to do this in one step, and not pipe the output of `git ls-files` to another process for subsequent filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pathspec should be `':(exclude,glob)**/foo/**'`.

The `:` after `)` is not necessary. Otherwise, it is interpreted as the first letter of the pattern, which is not what you expect.

The 2nd `**` refers to the files recursively or not recursively under `foo`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! One of my mistakes was assuming that it used `.gitignore` style formatting, where `**/foo` does seem to filter out `foo` anywhere in the tree.